# Proprietary ATI Driver fglrx kills my Video

Tags: drivers, ati, uninstall, proprietary

So, I'll explain the problem, but first I want to cry aloud PLEASE HELP!

I've used Ubuntu 12.04 for more than half an year and everything is set up just the way I want it. But I did a stupid mistake - I installed Proprietary ATI Driver fglrx.

Now the system boots normally, but after I choose to launch Ubuntu the screen goes black and my monitor doesn't receive any signals.

I tried some guides in recovery mode, but it's not working. Finally I started live cd and replaced files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ with original files. Still not working.

Please give me any ideas how to remove this killer!

Comment: Are you running a dedicated GPU, and if so, does your computer have an onboard video option on the motherboard?

Comment: I have GPU from this series - ATI Radeon HD 4000. I think I also have onboard chipset, but it wasn't a problem to this point.

Comment: You can pull out the GPU (or activate onboard in the BIOS, if you have that option), and plug the video cable into the motherboard. It might use the default drivers then, which will allow you to uninstall fglrx

Comment: Also, have you tried pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to a terminal? If that works, you can login and uninstall fglrx from there...

Answer (score 1):

Yey! I did it after reading some more. It was really annoying because when you boot without video, you have to shut down in inappropriate manner, so in recovery mode you get first some errors.

But the whole point is to get in recovery mode and type two lines:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Thank you Ash for your answers to my question.