# Monitor displays "signal out of limits" message after installing catalyst/fglrx

Tags: 12.04, ati, system-installation, catalyst

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 into my desktop PC (ATI Radeon HD 5570 Graphics Card, Monitor full HD LG W2240).

I tried to install ATI catalyst driver suggested  by Ubuntu system itself. When I tried to reboot, it keeps on giving me on a black screen the message signal out of limits 74.9 Khz / 60 Hz. The same message is given when I try to boot from the safe mode. I tried to use the instructions suggested by [this page](http://ubuntuguide.net/monitor-signal-out-of-range-problem-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-fresh-installation) but I couldn't achieve anything since it keeps on offering a login prompt where nothing is actually accepted.

Emil Athanasiou

Comment: Thank you for insulting us volunteers. We don't have any use for your email address, but we and other users searching for answers would have enjoyed if you put effort (how about formatting and a descriptive title?) into your question rather than hate.

Comment: Possible solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/296244/proprietary-ati-driver-fglrx-kills-my-video (uninstall the driver as it might not work with your card)

Answer (score 3):

If any software (driver too) is closed source (like what you installed) it isn't open to reviewing or improving anything.Closed software can be reverse engineered but it is problematic (legally too)

If you don't have to use closed source software then don't. When it is closed source no one knows what the code is except from who made it, so this is also a security issue.

## Set the correct resolution in GRUB to fix this issue

You can edit your **`/etc/default/grub`** to set the correct resolution.

Uncomment the line that contains `GRUB_GFXMODE` (remove`#`) and write your resolution such as 3840 x 2160 x 32. The line should then look like this: **`GRUB_GFXMODE=3840x2160x32`**

The fist two numbers are the resolution the third is color depth. Also set the correct screen refresh rate in GRUB.

> You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`, then do the edit. Finally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to leave. `sudo update-grub` will apply the changes.

Comment: Note that closed source can be reverse engineered with difficulty maybe even legal diffciulty too